# Self Study Textbook Progression from Griffiths QM to QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education

Hello Physics StackExchange!

I will put the TL;DR in the beginning: I need a self contained, relatively hand-holding sequence of textbooks that covers up from the end of Griffith's Intro to QM to relativistic QM/particle physics to QFT.

This will be my first post. I'm a medical physics grad student who majored in biomedical engineering for my undergrad, with serious regrets about not doing math/physics double major in hindsight. Oh well. I've made it my goal to eventually understand QFT.

My background in relevant subjects is Calc 1 to 3 and Diff EQ, 2 part freshman physics, an E&M course that used Griffiths Electrodynamics, a summer of self studying Griffith's QM (got most of the way through). I will also be officially taking a class in QM using Griffith's textbook this next spring. I am aware of the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian approaches to mechanics as well. In addition I have familiarity with special and basic general relativity using tensors and all this. What would be the best way for me to get from where I am now to a strong understanding of QFT autodidactically? I have no aversion to studying pure maths where I need to.

**To whomever might be tempted to mark my question as a duplicate**

My question is much different than simply asking for a handholding explanation of QFT per se. Generally these textbooks assume a certain amount of physics/math background, and I am asking for a *sequence of textbooks* leading up to QFT from the end of a specific textbook, Griffith's QM.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/224273/

Comment: Hi SSD. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: I did, and you didn't reopen it. Furthermore I don't even think you read my original question before closing it, because the "duplicate" you linked me to didn't address it at all and was unhelpful.

Comment: SSD, see my comment on your other question. You have to keep in mind that this site does not just exist to cater to you: You cannot expect your will to be carried out immediately, all the time.